# Using DOM elements defined in Handlebars template from Marionette view

Tags: javascript, dom, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I am using Marionette views with Handlebars templates.

Here is a sample view of mine:

```
(function() {

  'use strict';

  var root = this;

  root.define([...],

  function( Backbone, Tmpl ) {

      return Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({

          initialize: function() {},

          template: { 
              type: 'handlebars',
              template: Tmpl
            },

            ui: {},

          events: {},

          onRender: function() {
              var canvas = document.getElementById('stage');
          }
      });

      });

}).call( this );
```

In template `Tmpl` I create `<canvas id="stage"></canvas>`.

Just after loading this template I want to draw some beautiful things on canvas, but here is sad thing - `canvas` is not ready! I suppose there definitely should be some wrapper event, which is called after loading template. How should I rewrite my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `onShow`.

Render `triggerMethod` flow:

1. onBeforeRender – Before the view is rendered
2. onRender - After `.render` has been called, but before it's added to the DOM
3. onShow - After the view has been added to the DOM